# Nginx Ingress Controller producing 502 due to ambiguous path definition

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an ingress resource that is causing me 502 BadRequests on AWS ELB. The errors alternate 200, 502, 200, 502... etc for both services. I've ruled out issues with the services themselves. I'm confident in this because I can delete them and the ingress controller will then alternate between 502 and 503 errors

here is the ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-rules
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /(api/v0(?:/|$).*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend
                port:
                  number: 80
```

here is a describe of the Ingress:

```
Name:             ingress-rules
Namespace:        ingress-nginx
Address:          a9c8877f7b6184081b220f661e992b52-2001695431.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /(api/v0(?:/|$).*)   backend:80 (172.31.33.104:8080)
              /(.*)                frontend:80 (172.31.41.141:80)
Annotations:  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: true
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                 From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    19m (x28 over 18h)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

So the all too uncommon Unhealthy probe in the ingress resource isn't a problem that is showing itself in my logs.

ingress controller for nginx:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx

---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-configmap.yaml
#apiVersion: v1
#kind: ConfigMap
#metadata:
#  labels:
#    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
#    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
#    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
#    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
#    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
#    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
#  name: ingress-nginx-controller
#  namespace: ingress-nginx
#data:
#  http-snippet: |
#    server {
#      listen 2443;
#      return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
#    }
#  use-forwarded-headers: 'false'
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  ssl-redirect: "false"
  hsts: "true"
  server-tokens: "false"
  http-snippet: |
    server {
      listen 8000 proxy_protocol;
      server_tokens off;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/clusterrole.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: ingress-nginx
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - endpoints
      - nodes
      - pods
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - events
    verbs:
      - create
      - patch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingressclasses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/clusterrolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ingress-nginx
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx
    namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-role.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - pods
      - secrets
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingressclasses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
    resourceNames:
      - ingress-controller-leader-nginx
    verbs:
      - get
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
    verbs:
      - create
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - events
    verbs:
      - create
      - patch
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-rolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-nginx
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx
    namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service-webhook.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: https-webhook
      port: 443
      targetPort: webhook
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '60'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:XXXX:certificate/XXXXXXXXXXXX
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: elb
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: tohttps
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.44.0@sha256:3dd0fac48073beaca2d67a78c746c7593f9c575168a17139a9955a82c63c4b9a
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=nginx
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: LD_PRELOAD
              value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: tohttps
              containerPort: 2443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 90Mi
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/validating-webhook.yaml
# before changing this value, check the required kubernetes version
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#prerequisites
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
webhooks:
  - name: validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
    matchPolicy: Equivalent
    rules:
      - apiGroups:
          - networking.k8s.io
        apiVersions:
          - v1beta1
        operations:
          - CREATE
          - UPDATE
        resources:
          - ingresses
    failurePolicy: Fail
    sideEffects: None
    admissionReviewVersions:
      - v1
      - v1beta1
    clientConfig:
      service:
        namespace: ingress-nginx
        name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
        path: /networking/v1beta1/ingresses
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/clusterrole.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - admissionregistration.k8s.io
    resources:
      - validatingwebhookconfigurations
    verbs:
      - get
      - update
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/clusterrolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx-admission
    namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/role.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
      - create
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/rolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx-admission
    namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/job-createSecret.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-create
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ingress-nginx-admission-create
      labels:
        helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: create
          image: docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          args:
            - create
            - --host=ingress-nginx-controller-admission,ingress-nginx-controller-admission.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc
            - --namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
            - --secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission
          env:
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx-admission
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/job-patchWebhook.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-patch
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ingress-nginx-admission-patch
      labels:
        helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: patch
          image: docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          args:
            - patch
            - --webhook-name=ingress-nginx-admission
            - --namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
            - --patch-mutating=false
            - --secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission
            - --patch-failure-policy=Fail
          env:
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx-admission
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
```

Comment: Do you have the actual nginx config that your kub clusters generate, or actual error logs nginx is generating?  The info you provided is essentially useless w\o context.  200 Isn't an error, it's a "failed successfully" response.   502 is a bad request, which implies a completely different problem.   Sounds like there's a bucket load of disparate issues going on here, which may or may not have to do with your nginx config in the first place.

Comment: I just updated the question to add the ingress-controller definitions which are responsible for all of my nginx configuration, does this contain the config of which you're speaking? I don't see any errors in the nginx controller pod log outside of what I am describing (502s and 200s alternating on every request), but I can provide it anyway if useful.

Comment: 200 Isn't an error it's literally the "this succeeded" response.   That means your app was sending "this worked" with bad data (ie. your system didn't know how to interpret it).

502 is a bad gateway response.  Meaning there was a full stop error occurring.

These are two completely different issues, neither of which is likely caused by your controller directly.  200 = returning bad data, but the call "worked".  500 = server side fail.

A bad nginx config should only really be causing 4xx errors, since you don't seem to be doing any parameter type re-writes. .

Comment: Yeah no kidding the reason it is an error is because if you call the endpoint you will receive a 502 response.... the next response you will receive a 200 (e.g Ok, correct, this worked). make the same succession of calls You will once again receive a 502 followed by a 200. This is a repeatable and reproducible error.

 Now if you are suggesting this is not an error with nginx itself and something else perhaps the ingress resource paths conflicting, that too is my hunch.

Comment: Not sure how you’re getting confused here.  Pull your nginx log.  It will tell you what the issue is.  Lacking any sort of info on what is throwing the 502 error that’s the best advice I can give you…. Also again, 502 errors aren’t generally thrown by nginx itself but nginx will log the error if it’s thrown via fast pass.